# Simple jQuery textarea expand to fit content

Tags: jquery, textarea, height

In my attempt to build a simple cross browser expanding text area I found that all plugins seam far too overly cluttered.

I developed this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('textarea').keyup(function() {
        var txtheight = this.scrollHeight;
        $(this).height(txtheight)
    });
    $('textarea').keyup();
});​
```

It is producing unexpected results.

On FIREFOX it is working but if I delete lines from the textarea it does not reduce in size.

On CHROME the presseing of any key leads to another line height being added.

This is extremely confusing because if instead I change the code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('textarea').keyup(function() {
        var txtheight = this.scrollHeight;
       alert(txtheight); 
    });
    $('textarea').keyup();
});​
```

The alert gets the number correct every single time on both Browsers. What the hell is going on?

Comment: What about when the page/div loads for the first time with data?  And if the user copy-pastes some large text? Do you want to cover those cases too?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach that seems to work:

```
​$('#test').on('keydown', function(e){
    var that = $(this);
    if (that.scrollTop()) {
        $(this).height(function(i,h){
            return h + 20;
        });
    }
});​​​​​​​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/THM3D/).

Amended the above, in a slightly complicated manner but with, I think, proper accuracy:

```
function heightComparison(el) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var $el = $(el),
            clone = $('#' + el.id + '-clone'),
            cH = clone.height();

        $el.height(cH);

    }
}

$('#test').on('keyup paste', function(e) {
    var that = this,
        $that = $(that),
        clone = $('#' + that.id + '-clone').length ? $('#' + that.id + '-clone') : $('<div />', {
            'id': that.id + '-clone'
        }).css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'left': '-1000px',
            'border-width': '1px',
            'border-color': '#000',
            'border-style': 'solid',
            'overflow': 'hidden',
            'width': $that.width(),
            'min-height': $that.height(),
            'padding': $that.css('padding'),
            'font-size': $that.css('font-size'),
            'font-family': $that.css('font-family')
        }).appendTo('body');

    clone.text($that.val());

    heightComparison(that);
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/THM3D/3/).

Comment: Two things - the `.scrollTop() > 0` check. And the callback to `height()`! I wish I could upvote this twice!! Until today I always did `el.height(el.height() + n)`

Comment: The link itself isn't working (you're not able to get to JS Fiddle), or the example code found *at* that link (on JS Fiddle) isn't working?

Comment: @DavidThomas: Just for the fun of it, I have used `getComputedStyle` to find the incremental height instead of assuming `20`. [Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/THM3D/4/).

Comment: @DavidThomas But there are simpler ways of making it work with far less code

Comment: So use one of those approaches. I find my way works, it accounts for both increasing, and decreasing, the `textarea`'s height. Most of the `css()` could be moved into the actual stylesheet, and therefore simplified, which will make the jQuery more concise.

Answer (score 2):

Would not this work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('textarea').keyup(function() {
       var txtheight = $(this).scrollTop();
       $(this).css('height',($(this).height() + txtheight) + 'px')
    });
    $('textarea').keyup();
});
```

Simple effective solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late to answer the thread but you'll get a solution cooked enough :)

I just binded two events on `textarea` and thats all.

```
$('textarea').keypress(function (e) {
  // check if user pressed 'Enter'
  if(e.which == 13) 
  {
   // get control object to modify further
   var control = e.target;

    // get existing 'Height' of pressed control
   var controlHeight = $(control).height();

   //add some height to existing height of control, I chose 17 as my line-height was 17 for the control 
   $(control).height(controlHeight+17);
  }
});

$('textarea').blur(function (e) {

    // Here we get exact number of lines in our TextArea
    var textLines = $(this).val().trim().split(/\r*\n/).length; 

    // Now apply the number Of Lines * line-height to your control. That's all.
    $(this).val($(this).val().trim()).height(textLines*17);
});
```

It will grow your textbox while adding content in it, and also removes extra whitespaces ata the end. Check it out an **[example and fiddle](https://17path.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/resize-textarea-on-enter-pressed/)**