# Count Textarea Character and increase or Decrease size of the TextArea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to allow user to enter upto 300 character and simultaneously. I want to increase textarea based on user text if he deletes text, decrease textarea

https://jsfiddle.net/yhqdhr3x/

```
 <div id="divChar">300</div>
 <textarea id="txtpostSearch" class="form-control" rows="3" ></textarea>
```

JQuery Code

```
$('#txtpostSearch').keyup(function () {                
    var txtCharCountLength = $(this).val().length;
    if (txtCharCountLength <= 300) {
        var remainingChar = 300 - txtCharCountLength;
        $("#divChar").html(remainingChar);
    }
});
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12269010/1267304

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple jQuery textarea expand to fit content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268921/simple-jquery-textarea-expand-to-fit-content)

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown :  i want to count character also

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown : https://jsfiddle.net/yhqdhr3x/

Comment: For me the countdown is working.

Comment: in that link its show only row sizes increase and decrease

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown : i want to allow use to enter upto 300 character and simultaneously i want to increase textarea based on user text if he's delete text decrease textarea

Answer (score 0):

In your initialisation, put the following to prevent errors (this is for what keeps it less than 300 chars):

```
oldVal = "";
```

If you use a monospace font, and know the number of chars that fit in a row, each time the letter is typed, you could do the following on each character typed.... this assumes you can fit 22 chars on each row...

```
// save the element as variable, just to access without typing as much
elem = document.getElementById('txtpostSearch');

//if the length is above 300, set it back to what the value was before
if(elem.length > 300){
    elem.value = elem.value.substring(0, 300);
}

// the length of the contents of the textarea
len = elem.value.length;
// the new number of rows in the textarea
// it is the number of rows completely filled by text, plus two
// plus two makes room for the row currently typing in, and one more empty row
rows = Math.floor(len / 22) + 2;
// sets the height as the number of rows in units of font size
elem.style.height = rows + 'em';

//store the value in case the next length is too large
oldVal = elem.value;
```

I made a little fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5w7gogqt/

This fiddle uses a font called ProFont (if you dont have it, the fiddle defaults to plain monospace), which always has a set size no matter what OS or browser you use. You can always use a webfont for your field, then people use that font even if they don't have it.

Comment: after 300 Char also its allowing to enter text, i don't want to allow to enter after 300 char

Comment: Adding this  to my answer - I forgot about that.

Comment: where i have to add this

Comment: Add this to your `keyup` function for `txtpostSearch`. This way, every key that is typed will trigger the count of characters and block extra ones if the text is too long.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the number of rows and columns of the text area using JQuery.

To limit the number of input characters there's `maxlength` but it doesn't work consistently on all browsers, as an alternative you can just truncate the content of the textbox with `substring` and change the value of the textbox.

Demo:

```js
$('#txtpostSearch').keyup(function() {
  var str = $(this).val();
  var txtCharCountLength = str.length;
  
  if (txtCharCountLength <= 300) {
    var remainingChar = 300 - txtCharCountLength;
    $("#divChar").html(remainingChar);
    var rows = str.split("\n");
    var cols = rows.sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.length - a.length
    })[0].length;

    $(this).attr('rows', rows.length + 1);
    $(this).attr('cols', cols);
  } 
  else {
    $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, 300));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divChar">300</div>
<textarea runat="server" class="form-control" cows="3" id="txtpostSearch"></textarea>
```